# What are the differences between the command and the API to create a new core?

Tags: solr

I could create a new core by running the following command.

```
$ ./bin/solr create -c newcore

Setup new core instance directory:
/Users/myname/Documents/solr/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/newcore

Creating new core 'newcore' using command:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=newcore&instanceDir=newcore

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":916},
  "core":"newcore"}
```

However, I couldn't create a new core through the API that the message said.

```
$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=newcore2&instanceDir=newcore2'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">361</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Error CREATEing SolrCore 'newcore2': Unable to create core [newcore2] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/Users/myname/Documents/solr/solr-5.2.1/server/solr/newcore2/conf'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

What are the differences between these two ways to create a core? I understand why the error occurs this case. Is the process of the command not the same as the process of the API?
I'm using solr-5.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bin/solr create** command bootstraps the new core with one of the pre-existing configuration directories (by copying it from **server/solr/configsets**). You can see the options by running **bin/solr create_core -h** command. By default, you copy **data_driven_schema_configs**.

When you use API, Solr assumes that your core configuration is already present in the target location.

Comment: Which method is the idle one.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create cores/collections via bin/solr, or via cURL or via the Solr admin UI. They all in essence do the same thing.

The reason your second one (the cURL one) doesn't work is because you've got `instanceDir=newcore2` in the command, and that tells Solr to use the config from an existing core called newcore2. So if that core and its config doesn't exist, you'll get the whole "can't find that resource" error.

What I like to do is just alias the bin/solr file to 'solr', so that I can just type Solr commands in the terminal no matter what directory I'm in. I just open a terminal window, type `solr create -c potato` and there we go, new core. You don't have to `cd` into the directory or type some big gross cURL command or open up your browser and go to the admin UI. And of course bin/solr can do lots of stuff, not just core creation